# Print different strings from a sequence multiple times using tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print from a sequence randomly and print a different choice each time
Example:

```
import random
word = ("Python", "Apple", "Mountain", "Star Trek")
correct = random.choice(word)
print(correct * 3) # I'll get a single random choice printed three times 

#or 
for i in range 3:
   print(correct)
# I'll have again a single random choice printed three times.
```

What I want instead is to print three different choices with a single print command.

Comment: Cam you be more specific about which part you’re struggling with?

Comment: Thank you so much wjandrea for the editing. I am ashamed I couldn't express myself more clearly. Maybe this should be the subject of a separate satck overflow question, but how do you put the grey zone with the code in it. It is way nicer that the way I put it yesterday. Anyhow thank you again and many many thanks to the community.

Comment: _I am ashamed I couldn't express myself more clearly._ Don't worry :) You can find more information on formatting posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make 3 choices using `random.choices(list, k=# of choices)` and then print them out. This will give you 3 random words ***with*** replacement.

```
import random 
word = ("Python", "Apple", "Mountain", "Star Trek") 
choices = random.choices(word, k=3) 
for choice in choices:
    print(choice)
```

If you want 3 random words ***without*** replacement, consider using `random.sample(list, # of choices)`.

```
import random 
word = ("Python", "Apple", "Mountain", "Star Trek") 
choices = random.sample(word, 3) 
for choice in choices:
    print(choice)
```

Comment: For reference, "replacement" in combinatorics means that an item can be chosen more than once. (I just learned this myself.) I think OP wants *without* replacement.

Comment: Excellent answer you could also drop the for loop at the end and instead of calling the print statement 3 times in the loop. just call print once unpacking the choices list and using new line as the seperator `print(*choices, sep="\n")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers guys

Answer (score 0):

Choose randomly from the list, remove it, print it, and repeat twice.

```py
import random

def print3(items):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        item = random.choice(items)
        items.remove(item)
        print(item)

print3(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

Comment: It's easier to use `random.sample`, like in [Lapis Rose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869135/4518341)